# SQL Query pivot approach assistance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

i am really struggling with this pivot and hoped reaching out for help and enlightenment might help.

Say i have the following table....
Table A

```
type      actId date        rowSort   order value   value_char  colName
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
checking  1003   2011-12-31  2          1   44      44          Amount
checking  1003   2011-12-31  2          2   55      55          Interest
checking  1003   2011-12-31  2          3   66      66          Change
checking  1003   2011-12-31  2          4   77      77          Target
checking  1003   2011-12-31  2          5   88      88          Spread
savings   23456  2011-12-31  1          1   999     999         Amount
savings   23456  2011-12-31  1          2   888     888         Interest
savings   23456  2011-12-31  1          3   777     777         Change
savings   23456  2011-12-31  1          4   666     666         Target
savings   23456  2011-12-31  1          5   555     555         Spread
```

And i want to transpose to table b

```
checking  chkId date        rowSort   order chkvalue  chkValchar  colName  savings   savId  savVal  savValChar
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
checking  1003   2011-12-31  2          1   44        44          Amount    savings   23456  999          999           
checking  1003   2011-12-31  2          2   55        55          Interest  savings   23456  888          888           
checking  1003   2011-12-31  2          3   66        66          Change    savings   23456  777          777
checking  1003   2011-12-31  2          4   77        77          Target    savings   23456  666          666
checking  1003   2011-12-31  2          5   88        88          Spread    savings   23456  555          555
```

I can admit this is beyond my skills at the moment.
I believe i need to do a pivot on this table, using the rowSort (identify savings vs checking) along with ordering using the order column.  This maybe wrong and that is why i am here.

Is a pivot the right way to go?  Am i right to assume my pivot is to use the aggregate max(rowSort)?

Comment: There appears to be something missing from these sets of data - specifically, the customer ID. How else are you to know that checking account 1003 should be associated with savings account 23456? Also, what if a customer has multiple checking and/or multiple savings accounts?

Comment: you'll need to provide more details on your data... how does a checking row relate to a saving row is it based on order or colname? does date factor in? what do you need to see in rowSort? it's unclear how the data from table1 become the data in table2, you need to provide more details

Comment: @looktheninjas: It seems like you need grouping of data for each client based on `colName` and `order` where order seems to me a key that uniquly identifies `colName`. i.e. All records with colName as Amount together followed by Intereset doesn't matters it is checkings or saving. All this grouping will be for each customer. Can you please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rowSort` from `` `checking equal to rowSort+1 `` from `savings` and the rows link though `field value`, this should do it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

  a.type as checking,
  a.actId as chkId,
  a.date,
  a.rowSort+1,
  a.order,
  a.value as chkvalue,
  a.value_char as chkValchar,
  a.colName,
  b.type as 'savings',
  a.actId as savId,
  b.value as savVal,
  b.value_char as savValChar
  FROM tablea a
  INNER JOIN tablea b ON b.rowSort = a.rowSort+1 and b.value = a.value
```

Comment: Yes, you both are correct there is a customer id column which corresponds to the amount of checking savings mmarket accounts a customer would have.  Sorry for the confusion

Comment: aF i am getting back double double rows.  So instead of 5 rows i am getting 25 rows returned.

Comment: @looktheninjas I've put distinct, what about now? If you still have 25 rows please post the result on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirements you presented, you will not use a `PIVOT` for this query, you will want to `JOIN` your table to itself. The query below should give you the records that you want without having to use a `DISTINCT`

```
select c.type as checking
    , c.actId as chkid
    , c.date
    , c.rowsort
    , c.[order]
    , c.value as chkvalue
    , c.value_char as chkValchar
    , c.colName
    , s.type as savings
    , s.actId as savId
    , s.value as savVal
    , s.value_char as savValchar
from t1 c
inner join t1 s
    on c.rowsort = s.rowsort + 1
    and c.[order] = s.[order]
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cecb0/1)